# JSONDecodeError: Extra data: Python

Tags: python, json

I am loading json from files using the code:

```py
file = 'file_name'
obj_list = []
with open(file) as f:
    for json_obj in f:
        obj_list.append(loads(json_obj))
```

I get error:

```py
JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 21 (char 20)
```

All my files look like this but much larger.

```
{"some":"property2"}{"some":"property"}{"some":"property3"}
```

Is there a way to parse this in python for a large number of files?

Comment: The example you posted isn't valid JSON.  If they all look exactly like that (i.e., just one key/value, no nesting) you could probably write a custom thing to split them and then parse them separately as JSON.

Comment: Its not a JSON file.

Answer (score 2):

Your json is not valid . It should be something like this

```
[{'some': 'property2'}, {'some': 'property'}, {'some': 'property3'}]
```

Answer (score -2):

```py
import json
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    json_str = f'[{f.read()}]'
    obj_list = json.loads(json_str)
```

Reading the content, adding [] to make it valid json, and then loading it with  the `json` package.

Comment: This won't do it by itself, unfortunately. I'd take a closer look at the OPs sample data.